# Need help processing a ZIP file

Tags: php, zip

This is my scenario:

- I upload a zip file
- Check each file in zip file
- If file != image, then move file to destination
- if file == image, resize image and move to destination

I googled around and seen different solutions, but none where one can process files before saving them at the final destination.

This is the function I got so far:

```
  // Extract zip file and return files in an array. 
  private function processZip() {
    $zip = new ZipArchive;    
    $tmp_dir = FB_PLUGIN_DIR.'tmp/';

    // Extract files to tmp dir
    if ($zip->open($this->file['tmp_name']) === TRUE) {
      //Check if temp dir exists. If not, create one.
      if (!is_dir($tmp_dir)) {
        mkdir($tmp_dir, 0700);
      }

      $zip->extractTo($tmp_dir);
      $zip->close();

    /* Process extracted files */ 

    foreach(glob($tmp_dir.'*.*') as $filename) {

        // Somehow get MIME type here without using 'finfo' and 'mime_content_type'
        // I haven't installed PEAR and 'mime_content_type' is decapricated.
    }      

      return '1'; // success
    } else {
      return "0"; // fail
    } 
  }
```

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction here. Somehow I think I should be able to process the files while in the "ZIP loop".

Is there a way I can  read the files in the ZIP file, determin the MIME type and then process file?

I found this example: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=985
I think it's close to what I need. But not sure what to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decouple your processes.  Extract everything from the ZIP file first, then scan the files for image files and process them.

It's a simpler process, and can be more easily decomposed for dealing with larger zipfiles.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now. But I'm stuck on getting file info (MIME type). See my comments in code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've processed a zip file in the past without extracting the whole thing

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($file);
for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $entry = $zip->statIndex($i);
    if ($entry['size'] > 0) {
        $data = $zip->getFromIndex($i);
        // $data is a binary string of file data
        // which can be used in GD functions for images
        // and written to a location for regular files

        if (preg_match('/\.jpe?g$/i', $entry['name'])) {
            // JPEG file
        } else {
            // Not a JPEG file :-)
        }
    }
}
$zip->close();
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to actually read the file info without extracting it so I've gone with file extension detection.

Comment: The only problem, is that the file might not me what the extention says. That's why I want to read the MIME type.

Comment: If you're only interested in processing image files, you could just try running the string data through `imagecreatefromstring` which will return `false` if it is not an image file

Comment: yeah, I know. But the ZIP *might* have other file types.

Comment: @Steven yes, so as your question indicates, simply write the file data to the destination if `imagecreatefromstring` returns `false` ie, "If file != image, then move file to destination"